# Remove white border around the icon with active ColorOverlay in QML

Tags: qt, frontend, qml

When using QML ColorOverlay in QT 5.15, a white border appears around the image. Are there any options for removing it?

```js
Image {
    id: img
    source: "image.svg"
    width: 100
    height: 100
}

ColorOverlay {
    id: color_overlay
    anchors.fill: img
    source: img
    antialiasing: true
    visible: true
    color: black
}
```

I tried to add some margins around it, add/remove anti-aliasing and smooth, received the same result so far.

[icon with ColorOverlay and sad white border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSiNi.jpg)

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the problem with my own .svg image. But I wonder if it helps if you set img's `visible` property to false?

Comment: Sounds promising.. I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is your image is being rendered twice, the `Image` and `ColorOverlay` are drawing two versions of the image. A simple solution would be to hide your `Image` so you only see the `ColorOverlay`, i.e.

```
Image {
    id: img
    source: "image.svg"
    sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height) // highly recommended for SVGs
    width: 100
    height: 100
    visible: false
}

ColorOverlay {
    id: color_overlay
    anchors.fill: img
    source: img
    antialiasing: true
    visible: true
    color: "black" // N.B. "black" not black
}
```

Another issue with is to properly use SVGs with the `Image` component you really need to set `sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)`. This is because, without it, you may get a resampling degradation because the SVG `viewBox` often differs the `Image` dimensions.

Finally, with your `ColorOverlay` you need to specify `"black"` not `black` as the latter would result in an undefined value if you have not declared a Javascript property called `black`.

Alternatively, the approach I've always been using for recoloring SVG is via the `icon` property. The `icon` property solves the recoloring, the sampling, and the duplicate instance problems all at once, and, as a bonus, when using `Button.icon` you get the `onClicked` handler as well:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    IconButton {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: width
        icon.source: "smile.svg"
        icon.color: pressed ? "red" : "blue"
        onClicked: width < 200 ? width += 20 : width = 100
    }
}

// IconButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    id: iconButton
    width: 32
    height: 32
    clip: true
    property alias icon: button.icon
    property alias pressed: button.pressed
    signal clicked()
    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Item { }
        icon.width: iconButton.width
        icon.height: iconButton.height
        icon.color: "black"
        onClicked: iconButton.clicked()
    }
}

// smile.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path stroke="none" fill="yellow" d="M16 29.8A13.8 13.8 0 1 1 29.8 16 13.815 13.815 0 0 1 16 29.8zm0-26.6A12.8 12.8 0 1 0 28.8 16 12.815 12.815 0 0 0 16 3.2zm-4.5 10.6a1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608-.168 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608.168zm9.608-.168a1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0 1.216 0zm3.223 5.743l-.926-.379a7.863 7.863 0 0 1-7.39 4.976.166.166 0 0 0-.032 0 7.863 7.863 0 0 1-7.388-4.976l-.926.379a8.846 8.846 0 0 0 8.313 5.597.21.21 0 0 0 .035 0 8.848 8.848 0 0 0 8.314-5.597z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

[image: smiles.gif]